# React Native Country PickerView error when selecting a country

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a country picker view component from the  `'react-native-country-picker-modal'` package. When I click on it it opens a list of all the countries with their flag and code, but when i click on any one of the countries i get this error `"Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'countries[countryCode].name')"` and `"Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating str.indexOf)"`

here is my code:

```
import CountryPicker from 'react-native-country-picker-modal'

const [callingCode, setCallingCode] = useState('+1')
const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState('US')

<CountryPicker
                            style={{ height: 40, width: 60 }}
                            countryCode={countryCode}
                            translation={'ita'}
                            withCallingCodeButton
                            withAlphaFilter
                            withFilter
                            visible={false}
                            onClose={() => {
                                //   this.setState({showCountry : false})
                            }}
                            onSelect={(country) => {
                                setCallingCode(country.cca2)
                                setCountryCode(country.callingCode)
                            }}
                        />
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're setting the wrong variables, you're setting `countryCode` to the `callingCode` and `callingCode` to `cca2`

Comment: @YaakovAinspan is there a way to allow only some countries to show from the country picker?

Comment: I'd suggest looking thru [the docs](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal)